# Request for a new tag for Shiva trilogy

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

The Shiva trilogy by Amish Tripathi does not have a tag on this site. However I have a query regarding certain story elements, and due to the lack of any suitable tag (if there exists one I have not found it), I have been unable to post my query. Under these circumstances, what should I do?

Comment: Didn't I already edit one of your questions to contain this tag?

Comment: Oh, that was 15 minutes after you posted this.

Answer (score 4):

First off, **post the question with an already existing tag** - the generic [books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) tag might be a reasonable choice, since there isn't a specific one for the Shiva trilogy yet.

As soon as there's a question about the trilogy existing on the site, anyone with [at least 300 reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) will be able to **edit a new [shiva-trilogy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shiva-trilogy)<sup>1</sup> tag into it**; problem solved.

Edit: **[done](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/148888/31394)**.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Not just [shiva](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shiva), as that [might lead to confusion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=shiva+is%3Aq) with other Shivas appearing in other SFF works.</sub>